# nginx ngx_stream_ssl_preread_module inet

Tags: nginx

I've been scrolling through various forums, but I can't find a solution that uses the nginx Layer 4 proxy to forward to different backends based on the domain name curl requested。
For example the curl "https://storage.googleapis.com" - proxy IP: 8080, will get the backend2,
Curl "https://google.com" - proxy ip address :8080, the proxy will also go to backend2.
Whatever domain I request goes to default

I've been scrolling through various forums and can't find this solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
resolver 8.8.8.8 ipv6=off;
map $ssl_server_name $backend {
    ~^storage\.googleapis\.com$  backend1;
    default backend2;
}

upstream backend1 {
    server XXXX:80;
}

upstream backend2 {
    server YYYY:8080;
}

server {
    listen 8080 reuseport;


    proxy_protocol on;
    ssl_preread on;
    proxy_pass $backend;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).